# DB2: I want to see € or $ in the output of select

Tags: sql, db2

This simple query satisfy me

```
db2 => SELECT city,SUM(sales) as sum from offices group by city;

CITY                                                                                                SUM                              
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------
Rome                                                                                                                        14000,
Paris                                                                                                                         19000,
```

But..how to add the $ or € symbol? To get an output like this?

```
CITY                                                                                                SUM                              
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------
Rome                                                                                                                        14000$
Paris                                                                                                                         19000$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, this kind of formatting is left to the client to display.

If you really need to have the DB do it, then [VARCHAR_FORMAT](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSCJDQ/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007110.html) is likely a better choice.

```
select city
   , varchar_format(sum(sales),'$999G999G990D99' as sales 
from offices group by city;
```

The G and D characters represent the grouping and decimal character for your locale

Answer (score 0):

Solution found using the ||

```
select city,sum(sales) || '$' as sales from offices group by city;
```